# Working with generic model Problems with missing references on visual studio 2012 entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

EntityFramework
runtime v4.0.30319
version 5.0.0.0

```
public abstract class AbstractPessoaFisicaDao<T>:IBasePessoaFisicaDao<T> where T: class
{

    SupremaDesEntities entidades = new SupremaDesEntities();
    Cadastro_PessoaFisica Pessoa = new Cadastro_PessoaFisica();

    public void Add(T pEntity)
    {
        entidades.Cadastro_PessoaFisica.AddObject();
    }
```

Error   1   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'AddObject' and no extension method 'AddObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\msbow\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Inside.Net.EF\Inside.Net.EF.Data\AbstractPessoaFisicaDao.cs    26  45  Inside.Net.EF.Data

I was studying this in visual studio 2010, I now have the ultimate version 2012 and can not adjust this reference, already downloaded the framework and several dlls nothing.

Comment: Have you done a package manager install (or nuget) of entity framework for that project?  That is usually the fastest and easiest way to get all the .dll's.

Comment: Plus, it should be entidades.Cadastro_PessoaFisica.Add(object); not AddObject.

Comment: EntityFramework.dll should be in the box in VS2012 but you won't get it in VS2010 by default. In any case using nuget as suggested by @Scottie should fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SupremaDesEntities entidades = new SupremaDesEntities(); 

public void Add(T pEntity) 
{         
    entidades.Set<T>().Add(pEntity);
}
```

Or, if you want to keep the entity type strongly typed:

```
SupremaDesEntities entidades = new SupremaDesEntities(); 

public void Add(Cadastro_PessoaFisica pessoa) 
{ 
    entidades.Cadastro_PessoaFisica.Add(pessoa); 
}
```